# NSTableView sort problem(with KVC)

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

I had a weird problem on NSTableView sort.

I created a simple app with a NSTableView which
has 4 columns. Then I used KVC to bind it to a 
Array controller.

Then I added some data to the NSMutableArray.

Bulid&&Run the app and I can see the data inside
the table and by clicking the header the data can
be sorted correctlly.

Everything works fine up till now.

Then I tried to add the "caseInsensitiveCompare" to
each columns. So I opened the IB, set the sort key and 
selector ("caseInsensitiveCompare:") to each columns.

Then Bulid&&Run the app, but when I click the header to 
sort, I got the error message:

```
-[NSCFNumber caseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1006254f0
-[NSCFNumber caseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1006254f0
......
```

Then I tried to delete all the content in the sort key and 
selector of each columns. And the app became OK again.

What seems to be the problem? I am really confused...

ps:
If I use compare: instead of caseInsensitiveCompare:, everything works fine again...

Answer (score 0):

One of the values (such as a property or key) of your objects in your `NSMutableArray` is of class `NSNumber`.  Since this class deals with numbers, it doesn't respond to the `caseInsensitiveCompare:` selector.  This selector is meaningful to `NSString`.

The column on your table view that is displaying number values should keep using `compare:` for sorting the values.